# If I have a hash in Ruby on Rails, is there a way to make it indifferent access?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If I already have a hash, can I make it so that

```
h[:foo]
h['foo']
```

are the same?  (is this called indifferent access?)

The details:  I loaded this hash using the following in `initializers` but probably shouldn't make a difference:

```
SETTINGS = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/settings.yml")
```

Comment: `RAILS_ROOT` is deprecated in favor of `Rails.root`. You'll get crazy warnings if you use the old style.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can just use `with_indifferent_access`.

```
SETTINGS = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/settings.yml").with_indifferent_access
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore in Rails 3.2.8 at least. I have used this exact method for a while, and just tried to use it in a new 3.2.8 Rails app, but it doesn't seem that ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess is accessible in application.rb despite the fact that ActiveSupport is.

Comment: @slant That's because ActiveSupport has been modularized.  If you want this early in the app load process just require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/indifferent_access' up front.

Comment: @gtd Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for taking the time to explain that one.

Comment: Actually I managed to make it work with `require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'`

Answer (score 31):

If you have a hash already, you can do:

```
HashWithIndifferentAccess.new({'a' => 12})[:a]
```

Comment: so I think probably to use `SETTINGS = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/settings.yml"))` to begin with?

Answer (score 18):

You can also write the YAML file that way:

```
--- !map:HashWithIndifferentAccess
one: 1
two: 2
```

after that:

```
SETTINGS = YAML.load_file("path/to/yaml_file")
SETTINGS[:one] # => 1
SETTINGS['one'] # => 1
```

Comment: will it be ignored by other libraries that would read this file? you might have a settings file to share with a node server for example

Comment: Tested with [js-yaml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-yaml) and it doesn't work. So `!map:HashWithIndifferentAccess` is YAML tag and if the library can't understand it probably there will be an error.

Answer (score 6):

Use [HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) instead of normal Hash.

For completeness, write:

```
SETTINGS = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/settings.yml"­))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
You can just make a new hash of HashWithIndifferentAccess type from your hash.

hash = { "one" => 1, "two" => 2, "three" => 3 }
=> {"one"=>1, "two"=>2, "three"=>3}

hash[:one]
=> nil 
hash['one']
=> 1 


make Hash obj to obj of HashWithIndifferentAccess Class.

hash =  HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(hash)
hash[:one]
 => 1 
hash['one']
 => 1
```