# How to have the same behavior than 'params' function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

Controller functions receivent parameters like

```
{"v1" => { "v2" => "1", "v3" => "" }, "v4" => "true"}
```

The `params` function allows to use

- `x = params[:v1]`, equivalent to `x = params["v1"]`
- `if params[:v4]`, equivalent to `["true", "1"].include?(params["v4"])`
- `if (params[:v1][:v2] == 1)`, equivalent to `params["v1"]["v2"] == "1"`

Is there any method to have the behavior than `params` function, but with other datas ?

I want to be able to write something like that...

```
my_params = {"v1" => { "v2" => "1", "v3" => "" }, "v4" => "true"}
x = my_params[:v1]
if my_params[:v4]
if (my_params[:v1][:v2] == 1)
```

Or with a function `some_function`

```
x = some_function(my_params)[:v1]
if some_function(my_params)[:v4]
if some_function(my_params)[:v1][:v2] == 1)
```

**I'm in Rails 2.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861532/if-i-have-a-hash-in-ruby-on-rails-is-there-a-way-to-make-it-indifferent-access

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a [hash with indifferent access](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/with_indifferent_access):

```
h = { a: { b: 1, 'c' => 2 } }
=> {:a=>{:b=>1, "c"=>2}}
h[:a][:c]
=> nil


h2 = h.with_indifferent_access
=> {"a"=>{"b"=>1, "c"=>2}}

h2['a'][:c]  
=> 2
h2[:a][:c]
=> 2
```

Comment: I forgot something: I'm with Rails 2 ; with_indifferent_access is not available...

Comment: Sorry, I do a wrong click. I just remove it. with_indiferrent_access have just moved from class to another between Rails 2 and 3. Thanks !

Comment: yes it's there: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/indifferent_access.rb#L135